# Thyroid transplanted to the abdomen

Tags: homework, human-anatomy, endocrinology, human-physiology

This question was posed in our endocrinology class, however I have no idea how to answer it:

> The thyroid gland of a 5-year old boy is transplanted from its normal position in the neck to the abdomen (between the kidneys). Assume that the gland develops a good blood supply in its new position and that it remains alive.
>
> List the abnormalities that will develop in this child:
>
> 1. after two months.
> 2. after 10 years.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: We expect people to do their own research prior to asking and to present it with the question. Otherwise the question might be downvoted and/or closed due to no effort. So, what have you found out?

Comment: do you haver any ideas what would happen? what class is this for - a college level or graduate level course?

Comment: It's for a college level course. I haven't found anything that would suggest that this is a common, or even at all possible procedure. It seems to be purely theoretical.

Comment: I know removing the thyroid would affect the child's metabolism, but whether the gland would be at all viable elsewhere in the body I guess is the question. Presumably it would still function as a endocrine gland due to the blood supply, but would it receive the relevant tropic signals from the hypothalamus and AP?

Comment: so what do you think will happen? add that to your answer and it will give us an idea that you've tried to do a little thinking in your own...

Comment: You have the answer. Just back it up.

Comment: Thyroid gland is known to absorb iodine from food.It will not be able to absorb between the kidneys.